# Magento Bundled Product Restrictions

Tags: magento, bundle, compatibility

We need to represent computer systems on our Magento site.  We're going to use bundled products to represent these systems.  We'd like certain computer systems to have various options available (for example, mainboard, RAM, CPU, etc.).  However, we want to prevent our customers from configuring the system with incompatible parts (i.e. using DDR2 RAM in a mainboard that only supports DDR).  This doesn't seem to be possible in stock Magento.  Is there an extension out there that allows you to configure compatibility between bundled product options?  I'd like to know before I try tackling this on my own.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "I did it my own way" without providing access to the material that did it doesn't provide an answer that's usable to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself by writing my own module that uses attributes to determine compatibility.  It's not the cleanest solution and attributes aren't really meant for this purpose, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the question that you are asking, I have a serious doubt that you will find any such extension in the Internet. This is because how will the system (in this case, the product details page) know about the incompatibilities (like using DDR2 RAM in a mainboard that only supports DDR). This type of system intelligence can be performed, if there is some extra functionality provided in the backend, asking for which of the attributes / products will be incompatible with which all products.

Instead what I feel is it will be best if the administrator can provide correct options within compatible range directly for each such bundle product from the admin section, without the need for going to buy / search for an extension.

Hope it helps.